# Save input data to table on same page? HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am brand new to JavaScript and HTML, and am trying to make a rehersal booking app which collects the info needed and displays it in a table on the same page.
I have been trying for hours on end to get it to work with various methods and I feel like it's just getting worse. I have probably made some silly mistakes but I cant seem to work out what I need to change to make it work.

Here is my HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>White Noise Studios - Home</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Homepage.js"></script>
    <style>
        body, html
        {
            height: 100%;
            background: url(Media/background.png);
            background-size: cover;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<header style="color:white;font-family:'Calibri'">
    <h1> Rehearsal Bookings</h1>
    <p>Please let us know what gear you require in order for us to have the room ready for you. Leave the equipment section blank if you wish to bring your own gear. </p>
</header>
<form name="booking" id="booking">
<table style="color:white;font-family:'Yu Gothic UI Semibold'">
    <tr>
        <td><form action="Homepage.html"><input type="image" src="Media/homebutton.png"></form></td>
        <td><form action="Homepage.html"><input type="submit" value="Book My Rehearsal"></form></td>

        <td>Artist Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="Artist" size="50" id="Artist" /></td>
        <td>Contact Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="Contact" size="50" id="Contact" /></td>

    </tr>
        <td>Equipment Needed:</td>
        <td><label>Microphone</label>
        <select id = "Microphone" name="Microphone">
            <option value = "0">0</option>
            <option value = "1">1</option>
            <option value = "2">2</option>
            <option value = "3">3</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><label>Guitars</label>
            <select id = "Guitar" name="Guitar">
                <option value = "0">0</option>
                <option value = "1">1</option>
                <option value = "2">2</option>
                <option value = "3">3</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><label>Bass</label>
            <select id = "Bass" name="Bass">
                <option value = "0">0</option>
                <option value = "1">1</option>
                <option value = "2">2</option>

            </select></td>
        <td><label>Drums</label>
            <select id = "Drums" name="Drums">
                <option value = "0">None</option>
                <option value = "1">Mapex Mars 5 Piece Full Kit</option>
                <option value = "2">Ludwig LC17611 5 Piece Acoustic Kit</option>
                <option value = "3">Roland TD 25KV V-Drums Kit</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><label>Amp</label>
            <select id = "Amp" name="Amp">
                <option value = "0">None</option>
                <option value = "1">Marshall DSL100H</option>
                <option value = "2">Marshall MG100GFX</option>
                <option value = "3">Mesa Boogie triple Rectifier 100w</option>
            </select></td>    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Date:</td><td><input type="date" name="Date"  id="Date" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Time:</td><td><input type="time" name="Time" id="Time"  /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
<input type="submit" name="Book" value="Book my Rehearsal">

<button id="cancel" name="Cancel" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">Cancel</button>

<hr/>
<div id="table">
</div>
<body>
<body style=”font-family:”arial black”; >
```

And my JavaScript:

```
var ArtistField, ContactField, MicrophoneSelect, GuitarSelect, BassSelect, DrumsSelect, AmpSelect, DateSelect, TimeSelect, BookSelect, CancelSelect;


var Booking = function (Artist, Contact, Microphone, Guitar, Bass, Drums, Amp, Date, Time ) {
    this.Artist = Artist;
    this.Contact  = Contact;
    this.Microphone = Microphone;
    this.Guitar = Guitar;
    this.Bass = Bass;
    this.Drums = Drums;
    this.Amp = Amp;
    this.Date = new Date ;
    this.Time = Time;
};

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("booking").reset();
}

var Bookings = []

Booking.prototype.tableRow = function(){
    var tr = "<tr><td>" + this.Artist + "</td><td>" +
        this.Contact + "</td><td>" + this.Microphone +
        "<tr><td>" + this.Guitar + "<tr><td>" + this.Bass + "<tr><td>" + this.Drums + "<tr><td>" + this.Amp +"<tr><td>"
        + this.getDate() + "</td><td>" + this.Time+ "</td><td>" + "</td></tr> ";
    return tr;
};

Booking.prototype.getDate = function(){
    return this.Date.toDateString();
};

var clickBook = function() {
    addbooking(ArtistField, ContactField, MicrophoneSelect, GuitarSelect, BassSelect, DrumsSelect, AmpSelect, DateSelect, TimeSelect,);
    showTable();
};

var showTable = function(){
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("table"), table = "<table border='1'>" +
        "<thead><th>Artist</th><th>Contact</th><th>Microphone</th><th>Guitar</th><th>Bass</th><th>Drums</th><th>Amp</th</thead>";
    for(var i=0, j=Bookings.length; i<j; i++){
        var appt = Bookings[i];
        table += appt.tableRow();
    }
    table+="</table>";
    tableDiv.innerHTML = table;
};

window.onload = function(){
    ArtistField = document.getElementById("Artist");
    ContactField = document.getElementById("Contact");
    MicrophoneSelect = document.getElementById("Microphone");
    GuitarSelect = document.getElementById("Guitar");
    BassSelect = document.getElementById("Bass");
    DrumsSelect = document.getElementById("Drums");
    AmpSelect = document.getElementById("Amp");
    DateSelect = document.getElementById("Date");
    TimeSelect = document.getElementById("Time");
    //var roleChoice = roleField.options[roleField.selectedIndex].text;


    Book = document.getElementById("Book");
    Book.onclick = clickBook();
    showTable();
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by “save input data”? Merely write into an HTML table or save it to some data-storage (i.e. localStorage or a SQL database)? What is that `form` used for? The submit button is outside the form and it has no specific action!?

Comment: remove ',' for last one int this line     `addbooking(ArtistField, ContactField, MicrophoneSelect, GuitarSelect, BassSelect, DrumsSelect, AmpSelect, DateSelect, TimeSelec);` and   add '()' to this line -> `this.Date = new Date() ;`   these clears the errors